# Почему кровь голубая?

Tags: фразеология

Выражение "голубая кровь" для обозначения знатного происхождения у всех на слуху, но, если вдуматься: а почему, собственно, голубая? Я слышала только какие-то псевдонаучные объяснения, но, подозреваю, что есть более простое.
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А мне показалась интересной вот эта статья: http://oko-planet.su/phenomen/phenomendiscussions/140377-golubaya-krov.html

«Голубая кровь» как словесное выражение «аристократизма» появилось в лексиконе Европы не так уж давно - в XVIII веке. Самой распространённой версией считается, что свою «родословную» данный афоризм ведёт из Испании, а если ещё конкретнее, то из испанской провинции Кастилия. Именно так именовали себя надменные кастильские гранды,  демонстрируя бледную кожу с проступающими синеватыми прожилками. По их мнению, подобная синеватая бледность кожных покровов есть показатель исключительно чистых аристократических кровей, не осквернённых примесями «грязной» мавританской крови.

Но имеются и другие версии, по которым история «голубой крови» гораздо старше XVIII века, и уже в Средние века было известно о крови «небесного» цвета. Особенно внимательно к «голубой» крови относились церковь и святая инквизиция. В хрониках католического монастыря испанского города Витория зафиксирован случай, произошедший с... одним палачом.

Этот палач с большим практическим «опытом» был отправлен в данную обитель замаливать страшный грех - он казнил человека, который, как выяснилось, являлся носителем «голубой крови». Над палачом, допустившим непростительную «халатность», был учинён инквизиторский суд, который, внимательно рассмотрев необычное дело, вынес вердикт - казнённая жертва совершенно невиновна, поскольку люди с кровью цвета божественных небес не могут быть грешниками. Так что оплошавшему палачу пришлось каяться в святых стенах.

В хрониках XII века, написанных историком Альдинаром и повествующих о военных действиях между Англией и сарацинами, имеются такие строки: «Многократно изранен был каждый герой, но ни капли крови из ран не лилось». Данное обстоятельство указывает на то, что герои являлись обладателями «голубой крови». Почему?

Нет дыма без огня, и нет в нашей жизни простых случайностей. На пустом месте столь образное  выражение, как «голубая кровь», появиться не могло. И не могло в этом выражении быть крови никакого другого иного цвета. Только голубой.Энтузиасты, занимающиеся данным вопросом, утверждают, что голубая кровь всё-таки существует на самом деле, и «голубокровные» люди имелись всегда.

Эта особая группа представителей иных кровей чрезвычайно незначительная - всего-то около семи-восьми тысяч человек на весь земной шар. Таких «голубокровных» энтузиасты от «голубой крови» называют кианетиками.

Кианетики - это люди, в чьей крови вместо железа преобладает медь. Сам «голубой» цвет для обозначения необычной крови, скорее, красивый литературный эпитет, нежели реально отражённый факт, поскольку, на самом деле кровь, в которой преобладает медь, имеет лиловый с синью оттенок.

А вот ещё статья, мифологическая версия про богов:

http://nlo-mir.ru/sledybogov/446-rodina-bogov-golubaja-krov.htm
Родина Богов. Голубая Кровь

Comment: Ух ты, интересно как! Огромное спасибо за статью! Только ссылка не открывается(((

Comment: http://nlo-mir.ru/sledybogov/446-rodina-bogov-golubaja-krov.html

Answer (score 2):

Я слышал о такой версии: у аристократов, не обременных физической работой, кожа на руках нежная,тонкая, белая, и сквозь нее видны голубые ниточки вен, отчего возникает иллюзия  голубой крови.

Comment: Примерно так. Еще аристократы тщательно скрывались от солнца. Загар был удел крестьянок и прочих простых смертных.

Answer (score 1):

Читала где-то версию о том, что выражение "голубая кровь" связано с гемофилией (нарушение свертываемости крови), которая известна как наследственное заболевание. 
Болезнь эту называют болезнью "благородных кровей" и "венценосной болезнью". 
Именно высокой наследственной вероятностью обусловлено широкое распространение гемофилии еще в недалеком прошлом в венценосных кругах Европы, связанной традицией близкородственных браков. Причем, носителем гена является женщина, а болеют в большинстве своем только мужчины.

Comment: Носителем могут быть не только женщины, но и мужчины, а болеть - действительно,  только последние.